# Не запускаются старые проекты

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Скачал новую версию студии, и старые проекты начали выдавать ошибки. Не понимаю в чём проблема и как это пофиксить.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] И так во всех классах

Comment: а если сбилдить?

Comment: Я удалила все импорты и вручную заменяла на те, которые предлагала Studio. У меня там в основном были проблемы, решаемые заменой android на androidx...

Comment: Senior Pomidor, он даже не хочет билдиться

Comment: Надо проверить в свойствах проекта путь до JDK правильно указан?

Comment: Вы её (студию) рядом со старой что ли поставили? Проверьте путь до `SDK` (откройте `SDK Manager` и вверху увидите). Не поможет - показывайте выхлоп при попытке сборки

Comment: Можно попробовать удалить папку .grandle из проекта и сделать импорт проекта в студио

Answer (score 1):

У меня такое возникало, когда я менял Android SDK. Попробуйте вспомнить, какую версию android вы использовали в старом проекте и скачайте её через SDK Manager.